# едет верстка на IE

Tags: вёрстка

на IE 11 ломается простая верстка. Стоит Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta, верстка тремя колонками, ничего сложного. Не могу понять какой именно блок не нравится IE и как поправить ситуацию.

```css
<div class="bg-faded p-4 my-4">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="card col-md-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"> текст</p>
      </div>
      
    <div class="card col-md-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"> текст</p>
      </div>      

    <div class="card col-md-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text"> текст</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: вот так ломается]

Comment: [Тут написан подробный ответ по полной поддержке flexbox в ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979702/display-flex-not-working-on-internet-explorer/43979973)

Answer (score 0):

нашел [решение](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20321)

вкратце, IE (даже 11) не может в flexbox, поэтому надо жестко прописать показ колонок для разных разрешений:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">The title</h3>
                <div class="card-text">
                    The text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">The title</h3>
                <div class="card-text">
                    The text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">The title</h3>
                <div class="card-text">
                    The text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h3 class="card-title">The title</h3>
                <div class="card-text">
                    The text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

но почему мой 11 IE не смог до конца не понял, так как [заявлено что может](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow)